# How to store mathematical expression series into database as it is

Tags: sql, database

My requirement is to store this kind of series into a database:

[image]

Comment: what's wrong with simple text?, eg `B2CD,____, BCD4,B5CD, BC6D`

Comment: @Bohemian :- this is an mathematical expression we need to display like as it display in image

Comment: Don't confuse *data* with *rendering*. You shouldn't store renderings, unless you don't want to search it. If you just want to store an image, I would save the image on disk and store the filename in the database.

Comment: @Bohemian is right on with the distinction between data and its visual representation.

Answer (score 0):

Could you convert to and from LaTeX syntax on storing and retrieving the information? I don't know of any databases that support subscripts.

Comment: Can you explain the downvote? LateX seems to me like a reasonable tool for working with the kind of information you want to store.